# Browser cache resets on rebuild

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, browser-cache

I have a controller action that returns images from database. Those images are static, they will *never* change, and only time they "change", is when the image element is assigned a new ID.

I have assigned a

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ProductImages", Duration = 36000000)]
```

To the action,

```
<add name="ProductImages" enabled="true" duration="600000" varyByCustom="ProductImages" varyByParam="" />
```

In web.config->system.web->caching->outputcacheSettings->outputCacheProfiles and

```
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
```

Under system.webserver->staticContent.

I build it, refresh the page, images get fetched. I refresh the page again, images are taken from cache. However, when I change a line of code, rebuild, refresh again... all the images get re-fetched from the database. Not only are there thousands upon thousands of images stored in the database, but it's going to be deployed in Windows Azure, so optimization is highly important.

Note that standard "static content" remains cached, such as Site.css and JQuery.js. What doesn't, however, is the images.

The image access URL is always static, going by form of
~/Media/Image/1a00d817-6525-4d13-82bc-d0f24d26f29c

I have no idea how to go about fixing that, because while it's tolerable during development, if if every time I redeploy to Azure, everyone's image cache gets reset... *shivers*.

Ideas are welcome!

EDIT:

I've also tried adding an extension to the end of the URL (like .jpg), so browser would think of it as static content, and added a

```
<add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" location="Client" duration="365.00:00:00"/>
```

to system.webserver->caching->profiles, but to no avail.

Headers with darin's suggestions enabled (always re-requesting):

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=600000
Content-Length:4593
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Tue, 19 Feb 2013 08:55:27 GMT
Expires:Tue, 26 Feb 2013 07:35:26 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 19 Feb 2013 08:55:26 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:4.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Headers with location="Any" (re-requesting upon rebuild only):

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=600000
Content-Length:21461
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Tue, 19 Feb 2013 08:57:03 GMT
Expires:Tue, 26 Feb 2013 07:37:03 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 19 Feb 2013 08:57:03 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Vary:*
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:4.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cache them on the client to avoid hitting the server each time:

```
<add 
    name="ProductImages" 
    enabled="true" 
    duration="600000" 
    varyByCustom="ProductImages" 
    varyByParam="" 
    location="Client" 
/>
```

Comment: Specifying Client as location makes them request it every single time, funnily enough, so this doesn't work :/

Comment: You seem to be using some `varyByCustom` method. Maybe there's the problem. You mentioned that cache should vary by image id, so I guess that your controller action takes an `imageId` parameter. You could then set `varyByParam="imageId"` and get rid of the `varyByCustom` method.

Comment: The parameter the action takes is indeed called "id", but even if I remove varyByCustom and put varyByParam="id", same happens, it keeps getting requested on refresh. Only "Any" works, and only until I rebuild the project. I haven't tried it on an actual IIS server, just the VS development one, perhaps that might be a problem... but then again, it's the browser cache. I don't even want it to go requesting the images again, ever, if it already has them in cache.

Comment: Could you show the HTTP response headers that the server returns when you first request the image?

Comment: Done. Also added Any headers.

Comment: Note that it's only when I use F5 does it re-request them. Normal navigation gets them from cache with 200 response, even after rebuild. What I want however, is to always have them cached, even with refresh.

Comment: Also, this is in chrome. Firefox refuses to cache entirely when I refresh, regardless of settings.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to reproduce this issue. This is working fine for me.